# Modify numpy array inside a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pass-by-reference

I want to modify a `numpy` array passed to a function. The solution should modifies its shape **without** the need to returning it.

For example, the following works and prints correctly `[3,4]`

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([-1,-2])
def foo(a,b):
    b[:] = a+2
foo(a,b)
print(b)
```

My interest is in cases where there is a shape mismatch. For example, the following gives error *'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2,)'*

```
def foo2(a,b):
    b[:] = np.outer(b,a)
foo2(a,b)
```

> How to modify the function `foo2` to change the content of b?

After `foo2(a,b)`, `print(b)` should print

```
[[3 6]
 [4 8]]
```

Comment: The return from np.outer is 2*2 array and you want to assign it to 2*1 array. This is the problem

Comment: Shape and dtype of an array cannot be changed in-place.  There are a couple of exceptions, `b.shape=(3,4)` and `b.resize(3,4)`, but their use is restricted, and not applicable to your case.

Comment: Some `ufunc` like `outer` take an `out` parameter, but its shape has to right to start with.

Comment: Yes, my interest is exactly in how to do this kind of things when there is a shape mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You have a shape problem. But still I tried something that would work.

```
def foo2(a,b):
    b = b.astype(dtype=object)
    x = np.outer(b,a)
    b[0] = x[0].astype(int)
    b[1] = x[1].astype(int)
    b = np.concatenate(b).reshape(x.shape)
    print(b)
foo2(a,b)
```